# What is the proper way to retrieve a listview items value in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tlistview

Right now I am using the following code to get a ListView items value and I was wanting to know if this was the proper way to do this or should I be doing it another way.

**Example for the parent item value:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(ListView1.Selected.Caption);
end;
```

**Example for a sub item value:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(ListView1.Selected.SubItems.Strings[items_index_here]);
end;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first code seems fine, except you should be checking to see if there is a `Selected` item first:

```
if Assigned(ListView1.Selected) then  // or ListView1.Selected <> nil
  ShowMessage(ListView1.Selected.Caption);
```

Your second can be simplified (and should include the same check I mentioned above):

```
if Assigned(ListView1.Selected) then
  ShowMessage(ListView1.Selected.SubItems[Index]);
```

`TStrings` descendants (like `TStringList` and `TListItem.SubItems`) have default properties, which is a shortcut to using `TStrings.Strings[Index]`; you can instead just use `TStrings[Index]`. Instead of `MyStringList.Strings[0]`, you can just use `MyStringList[0]`, and this applies to things like `TMemo.Lines` and `TListItem.SubItems` as well. You don't need `SubItems.Strings[Index]`, but can just use `SubItems[Index]`.

Comment: Appreicated and I am doing the error checking in my production code, I just whipped the above code up off the top of my head.